# What's a convenient way to call lists of arguments, but each time only using items at the same positions?

Tags: haskell

I know that there's a very useful concise pattern in Haskell for applying a function to a list of arguments:

```
λ> rem <$> [23, 45] <*> [7, 11]
[2,1,3,1]
```

is there a similar convenient way to only call the the items in the same corresponding indices? In the above example, it would be only `rem 23 7` and `rem 45 11`, instead of all possibilities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `zipWith`:

```
zipWith rem [23, 45] [7, 11]
```

If you have more lists, there are `zipWith3`, `zipWith4` etc.

You can also use the `ZipList` applicative:

```
getZipList $ rem <$> ZipList [23, 45] <*> ZipList [7,11]
```

Comment: +1 for the `ZipList` abstraction, which generalizes `zipWithX`. Side note for newcomers: `pure x = [x,x,x,x,...]` for `ZipList`, which is the right choice for this `Applicative` instance, but not obvious.